# Plotting graphs using columns from an imported csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, graph, multiple-columns

I imported data into my R workspace from an csv file.

```
>tbl <- read.csv("BitcoinData.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Then displayed the table

```
>tbl
time   timeDate          close     high     low      open  
1   1.51e+12 12/24/2017 12615.06 12796.90 12428.77 12741.11
```

Then I wanted to plot the high and low using the columns, as my data extends down for 200+ rows.

I tried

```
plot(high, low)
```

And got

```
Error in plot(high, low) : object 'high' not found
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
plot(tbl$high, tbl$low)
```

you need to let it know where those variables live... thanks for the easy one!